# How to read/write a/from a file in javascript with prototype.js/jQuery.twFile support OR anyotherway

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, file-formats, jquery

I want to write my data into a file from OpenLayers, I have gone through Prototype.js and jQuery.twFile.js or anyother way to write into a file.

Answer (score 2):

To write to a local file from a web page, you would likely need to use silverlight or flex. Browser support for writing to local files using javascript is inconsistent, bleeding edge.